# PSU Issues - Antect 1000w Quattor

Tags: power-supply, hardware-failure

I have a server using a 1000w PSU from Antec. My Raid 6 was becoming degraded and I tried to repair without success.  So I have looked at the drives and they are all operational. I have now found that 1 of the 4 cables is successfully supplying power.

My question is:

1. Does this sound like I have lost 3 of the 4 12v rails and with my trusty soldering Iron I maybe able to fix the problem ***OR***
2. Replace the thing with a new one

**Note 1**: The server will actually boot up and run fine, I just cannot use any HDD connected to the other modular plugs. Swapping the cables gives the same results, so I believe not a cable issue.

**Note 2**: Multimeter tests not performed at this stage.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out was a combination of things:

1. The SATA2 connection only supports 1 active drive due to the inbuilt RAID
2. The PSU modular plug has finally decided to not supply power

Setting the board up correctly and the PSU power cable swapout, everything is as it should be.

FYI - this all confirms that the Adaptec RAID has an issue and not able to successfully build and hold raids after running continuously for 5 years